# Add checkbox to excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Suppose I have three columns; Column A, Column B and column C. How to add checkbox using VBA automatically in column A if I put text in Column B (only) not Column C, and when I delete that text, remove Checkbox from m Column A

Comment: Possible duplicate of [insert check box to a particular cell through vba macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16992195/insert-check-box-to-a-particular-cell-through-vba-macro)

Answer (score 0):

Insert a checkbox (Active X control) on your sheet and try the following code :

```
If sheets("Test").range("a1")<>"" then
sheets("Test").combobox1.visible=true
else
sheets("Test").combobox1.visible=false
end if
```