# Get Checkbox location and name?

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to have VBA return the location of a checkbox, the linked cell, and the name of the checkbox?

I am building a spreadsheet that has 100's of check boxes. It is crazy linking all these cells, then having to have helper cells to fill data in a report. What I am thinking is having VBA return the location, linked cell, and checkbox name. If I can get those, I can automate most of this. But I am hoping to have one macro work on all checkboxes. Kind of an on change type of command and if that change is a checkbox being marked then it would pull that data and write it where it needs to be.

So in turn, I get rid of the helper cells, and Only have to name the checkbox. That name would be the value I want filled.

I can modify code and work with macros, but not sure how to get the data. Any help is appreciated, or if there's a post somewhere that would help, please point me in the right direction.

Comment: Perhaps use vba to _Create_ those checkboxes instead??? [Analysistabs.com example](https://analysistabs.com/vba/add-checkbox-on-worksheet-or-userform-using-vba/) or https://stackoverflow.com/q/16992195/3654325.

Comment: Create a sub and set all checkboxes' `OnAction` to that sub.  Within the sub use `Application.Caller` to get the name of the clicked checkbox, and feed that into `ActiveSheet.Checkboxes(nameHere)` to reference the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

This is an extremely basic bit of code that gets them for you, what you do with that is up to you.

```
Public Sub PrintCheckboxes()
    Dim objShape As Shape

    For Each objShape In Sheet1.Shapes
        With objShape
            If .FormControlType = xlCheckBox Then
                Debug.Print "Checkbox Name = " & .Name & ", Title = " & .AlternativeText & ", Linked Cell = " & .ControlFormat.LinkedCell & ", Top Left Cell = " & .TopLeftCell.Address
            End If
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

Adapt accordingly.